# QUEUE=* not found error on Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, worker, foreman

I'm trying to use foreman to run my app locally, using the same Procfile I use when deploying my app on Heroku, where it works perfectly. However, when running `foreman start` on my terminal, foreman gives an error saying:

```
line 41: exec: QUEUE=*: not found
```

What I gather from this is that foreman doesn't recognize `QUEUE=*` as a command. So why does it work on Heroku? And what can I do to run the command exactly as it is run in production mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.  You want to put the queue param at the end.

eg:
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=hi

Comment: Same problem for me after adding multiple queues. A quick Googling ended here - thanks Nader for the fix!

Comment: @Nader In heroku it is not working. Is there any different syntax for heroku ?

Comment: @Nader In fact, I have two queues and I would like to run those two in parallel. So if we follow that syntax then workless can't pic up the other worker. So is there any alternate solution?